# Click anywhere on body to perform a function: directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have created a directive, which will enable a user to click on a word
to edit it in a text box and then whenever and wherever on body is clicked it should get back to the edited word.

**html**

```
 <div markdown>bineesh</div>
```

**JS Directive**

```
app.directive('markdown',function () {

/*var htmlText='<textarea cols="20" rows="10" ng-show="isEditMode" ng-dblclick="previewSwitch()" ng-model="markdown"></textarea>';*/
var htmlText='<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-hide="isEditMode" ng-dblclick="backToTextarea()" ng-model="markdown"/>';
var newHtml='<div ng-click="previewSwitch()" ng-show="isEditMode" >{{markdown}}</div>'
var dir={
    restrict:'A',
    compile:function (tElement,tAttrs,transclude) {
        var markdown=tElement.text();

        tElement.html(htmlText);
        tElement.append(newHtml);

        return function (scope,element,attrs) {
            scope.isEditMode=true;
            scope.markdown=markdown;

            scope.previewSwitch=function () {
                scope.isEditMode=false;
            }
            scope.backToTextarea=function () {
                scope.isEditMode=true;
            }
        };


     }
   }
  return dir;
});
```

I know that something needs to be added in the directive, but I am not getting into it properly, as I am new to Angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
angular.element(document).on('click', function() {
  scope.isEditMode = false;
});

element.on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: yeah this somewhat works, but when i click on textbox to edit, it gets into its old state,since i have added ng-dblclick still it is closing on single click

Comment: the simplest solution is to catch the click on the markdown and return false in the callback

Comment: m sorry, but could u explain me in details, as I said I am new to Angular

Comment: well it is working, but I have to dbclick instead of click to get it into same old state. Can not we make in single click on body, and dblclick on textbox?

Comment: You can do it. also you can call scope.previewSwitch() from the element click handler

Comment: finally got it, directives are very new to me, and it gets complicated whenever I try to code on to it. Thanks for helping out